# My WriteConcatenated method doesn't work because of BC30491

Tags: arrays, vb.net, methods, subroutine, paramarray

```
Imports System

Module Program
    Sub WriteConcatenated(ByVal ParamArray TextArr As String())
        For I As Integer = 0 To TextArr.Length - 1
            For J As Integer = 0 To TextArr.Length - 1
                Dim ConcatenatedText = TextArr(I) + TextArr(J)

                For Each Text As String In TextArr
                    If Text = ConcatenatedText Then
                        Console.WriteLine(Text)
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        Next
    End Sub

    Sub Main(args As String())
        Console.WriteLine(WriteConcatenated("five", "cents" "twenty", "twentycents"))
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

If there is a element which formed by the concatenation of other elements of the parameter array, I wanted to print them to the screen.

For example: "twentycents" which is at 3rd index in above-mentioned parameter array is concatenation of "twenty" which is at 2nd index and "cents" which is at 1st index in the array. Then the 3rd element of the array will be printed to the screen.

There is no error in code as far as I am concerned but, compiler of Visual Basic gives me

**BC30491: Expression does not produce a value**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/error-messages/expression-does-not-produce-a-value?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(BC30491) (Document of the error)

How should I correct this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WriteConcatenated()` is a subroutine that does not "return" a value.

Change:

```vb
Console.WriteLine(WriteConcatenated("five", "cents" "twenty", "twentycents"))
```

to:

```vb
WriteConcatenated("five", "cents" "twenty", "twentycents")
```

And it will work.

On the other hand, if `WriteConcatenated()` was a function declared using the `Function` keyword that returned a value using the `Return` keyword, passing the value returned by it to `Console.WriteLine()` like you've done would have worked.

Comment: Yes @galdin, thanks! This method already writes something to the screen. Calling WriteLine method for second time doesn't make sense. This is totally my inattention.